# invalid cross reference id while Creating a new User in SalesForce

Tags: salesforce

while Creating a new User in SalesForce If I Give a ProfileID which is already exists.

invalid cross reference id

```
User[] AddUser = new User[1]; 
User objuser = new User { Username = "balaji.balumca@gmail.com", 
             Alias = "Balu", // The ID of the user profile (Standard User, System Administrator, etc). 
             ProfileId = "00590000002Px2vAAC", 
             Email = "balaji.balumca@gmail.com", 
             EmailEncodingKey = "ISO-8859-1", 
             FirstName="Balaji",
             LastName = "Balu",
             LanguageLocaleKey = "pt_BR", 
             LocaleSidKey = "pt_BR", 
             TimeZoneSidKey = "America/Sao_Paulo" }; 
AddUser[0] = objuser; 
SaveResult[] saveResults = _service.create(AddUser);
```

Comment: User[] AddUser = new User[1];
User objuser = new User 
{
Username = "balaji.balumca@gmail.com",
Alias = "Balu",
// The ID of the user profile (Standard User, System Administrator, etc).
ProfileId = "00590000002Px2vAAC",
Email = "balaji.balumca@gmail.com",
EmailEncodingKey = "ISO-8859-1",
FirstName="Balaji",
LastName = "Balu",
LanguageLocaleKey = "pt_BR",
LocaleSidKey = "pt_BR",
TimeZoneSidKey = "America/Sao_Paulo"
};
AddUser[0] = objuser;

SaveResult[] saveResults = _service.create(AddUser);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ProfileId="00590000002Px2vAAC" however 005... is not a profile its a user, profiles start with 00e. Use one of the schema/query tools (e.g. SoqlX, Eclipse Plugin, etc) to find the right profile Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void CreateUser()
        {
            var _service = new SforceService();
            var login = _service.login(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);

            User[] AddUser = new User[1];
            User objuser = new User
            {
                Username = "Pavankumar.r@gmail.com",
                Alias = "RPK",
                // The ID of the user profile (Standard User, System Administrator, etc).
                ProfileId = "00e90000001CcTnAAK",
                Email = "Pavankumar.r@gmail.com",
                EmailEncodingKey = "ISO-8859-1",
                FirstName = "Pavan",
                LastName = "Kumar",
                LanguageLocaleKey = "pt_BR",
                LocaleSidKey = "pt_BR",
                TimeZoneSidKey = "America/Sao_Paulo"
            };
            AddUser[0] = objuser;

            SaveResult[] saveResults = _service.create(AddUser);
            string result = "";
            if (saveResults[0].success)
            {
                //
            }
            else
            {
                //
            }
        }
```